# Should I create a 8 GB swap file on my amazon image?

Tags: amazon-ec2, swap

I have an Amazon image with 1 root image, 1 image that I uses for websites and is only using 25%, and 1 image "unused"

So I thought... maybe I can use that unused image for a linux swap file.

Since I have 10 Gb (9.2G Avail)  would it be wise to create a 8GB swap file on this Volume or would that not be best practice? (I run some WordPress sites only) (memory = 3.75GB)

Can I somehow tell "use the complete disk as swap space" instead of indicating the specific amount?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/web2/swapfile bs=1024 count=8388608
mkswap /mnt/web2/swapfile
swapon /mnt/web2/swapfile
```

and

```
[root@ip-* web2]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3754       3715         38          0         11       3517
-/+ buffers/cache:        186       3567
Swap:         8191          0       8191
```

and

```
[root@ip-* etc]# cat fstab
#
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
web         /dev/xvdf   ext3    defaults        1   1
web2        /dev/xvdg   ext3    defaults        1   1
/mnt/web2/swapfile swap swap    default         0   0
```

Comment: Why even do this? Are you actually running out of physical memory?

Comment: I was - reason not completely clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need swap space then use instance storage instead of EBS volumes.  There are 3 reasons:

1. Instance storage will be faster
2. You'll pay for the EBS I/O
3. You don't need the swap space to persist beyond restarts